# How do I make my bot check if you have a role from a different server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im trying to make a premium only command for my discord bot, but it checks if a user has a specific role from my support server, I want the bot to be able to check if the user has the role from my support server while its in other servers, how would i do that? here is  my current code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("s!premium")){
    let user = message.author.username
    console.log(`${user} checked there premium status`)
    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '1091889400570454016')){
      message.reply("You have StarStruct Premium!")}
    else{message.reply("The only way to get StarStruct premium is to join the support server, where we host giveaways! https://discord.gg/B9c4ceGhUR")}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, <Guild> is your support guild.

You can do:
`<Guild>.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.cache.has('role id')`\

This returns a true or false depending on if the member has the role.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by <Guild> is my support guild? do I define it as the servers id or what?

Comment: @AkaTech sorry for the late reply, but no, you need to replace it as a Guild object.
`client.guild.cache.get('server id')`